# Manipulating a path into an email address

Tags: unix, sed, grep

I have a file with the following contents,:

```
./E/domainname.com/martin    
./s/domain2.com/shelly    
./E/2/4domain.com/john    
./X/another.net/gary
```

I want to output:

```
martin@domainname.com    
shelly@domain2.com
```

and so forth.

I have been trying to isolate the users names first by searching backwards in the lines until I hit a `/`, but I have failed so far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use awk:

```
awk -F/ '{printf "%s@%s\n",$NF,$(NF-1)}' input.file
```

`-F/` marks the `/` as the field delimiter. Using `$1`, `$3`, ... you can access the fields. `$0` represents the full record. `NF` represents the number of fields in a row. Knowing this, you can use `$NF` to select the last field in a row and `$(NF-1)` to select the second last field and printf them using a `@` as delimiter.

Comment: Well done! I did a minor edit. I already +1, so I cannot again :)

Comment: Thank you very much.  This worked beautifully and taught me a thing or two about delimiters.  Great you took the time to write out the explanation.  I'd +1 if I could.

Answer (score 5):

You could try the below sed command.

```
$ sed 's~.*/\([^/]*\)/\([^/]*\)$~\2@\1~g' file
martin@domainname.com
shelly@domain2.com
john@4domain.com
gary@another.net
```

**Explanation:**

- `.*/` Matches all the characters from the start upto the `/` symbol(2nd forward slash symbol from the last).
- `\(...\)` Called capturing group, which was used to capture characters.
- `[^/]*` Matches any character but not of `/` zero or more times. So the combined `\([^/]*\)` would capture all the characters  exists before the last `/` symbol.
- `/` Matches the last forward slash.
- `\([^/]*\)`  Captures all the chars but not of `/` zero or more times into another group.
- `$` Denotes the end of the line.
- In the replacement part, back-referencing the captured group like `\1` , `\2` will print the chars inside the corresponding group.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I am having trouble understanding the logic here though.  SED was my first thought on what to use, but I'm too new and got lost.

Answer (score 1):

With bash builtins (Parameter Expansion):

```
#!/bin/bash

while read LINE; do
    NAME="${LINE##*/}"
    DOMAIN="${LINE%*/$NAME}"
    DOMAIN="${DOMAIN##*/}"
    echo "$NAME@$DOMAIN"
done < filename
```

Output:

```
martin@domainname.com
shelly@domain2.com
john@4domain.com
gary@another.net
```

An alternative with sed:

```
sed -E 's|^.*/(.*)/([^ ]*)|\2@\1|' filename
```

Comment: I see this SED is almost the same as the one from Avinash Raj.  I'm afraid I get lost.  If there is time for an explanation I'd love it.